# Javascript ternary operator usage

Tags: javascript

Is the below valid JS code?

```
response.continueRequest = (response.continueRequest == undefined) ? false : response.continueRequest;
```

response is actually an AJAX response object.

Comment: Try it and you tell us. ...

Comment: The ternary looks valid, but have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Consider: `response.continueRequest = response.continueRequest || false`.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is, it means

```
if (response.continueRequest == undefined){
    response.continueRequest = false;
}else{
    response.continueRequest = response.continueRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a valid JavaScript code. It could be also shortened:

```
response.continueRequest = response.continueRequest ? response.continueRequest : false;
```

The type coercion in JavaScript converts `response.continueRequest` to boolean, and if it is true, than the actual value of `response.continueRequest` is assigned, otherwise `false` is assigned.

Going this way is more logical, although you could do it as initially in your example:

```
response.continueRequest = !response.continueRequest ? false : response.continueRequest;
```

However this line gives a hint something else in your code isn't really nice solved, if you really need to do this.

EDIT:

You can use `response.continueRequest` in a condition:

```
if (response.continueRequest) {
    // condition body
}
```

If `response.continueRequest` is `undefined` it is `false` by type coercion and it doesn't enter the if-clause. I guess, something like this is what you're aiming for.

And keep in mind that `undefined` is not the same as not defined. Example:

```
var something;
console.log(something); // undefined
console.log(nothing); // Uncaught ReferenceError: nothing is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the '===' operator

```
response.continueRequest = (response.continueRequest === undefined) ? false : response.continueRequest;
```